# How do I get browser Autofill values to show up in my serialized React `Field` component data?

Tags: javascript, forms, autofill, reactjs

I have a `Form` component that I am building in React and this form has some `Field` components as children. I am using these components to build a log in form that has an email address and password. My form has an `onSubmit` handler that serializes its children (`Field`s) and sends off an AJAX request.

Everything is working well in the normal case. But, when browsers like Chrome [Autofill](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en) the form with my email address and password, the serialization doesn't pick up the values of the inputs.

`Field` currently looks something like this:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Field = React.createClass({
  serialize: function() {
    return { name: this.props.name, value: this.refs.field.state.value };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {this.props.label}
          <input type={this.props.type} ref="field"
            name={this.props.name}
            defaultValue={this.props.value} />
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

**How do I get the browser Autofill value to show up in my serialized `Field` data?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State should flow in one direction, from the top layer down to the bottom. So reaching into a child element to get its state is a bad idea. To accomplish the serialization with this structure, you simply need to reach into the DOM to get the value of the input. In the code example above, the `serialize` method should be:

```
serialize: function() {
  return { name: this.props.name, value: this.refs.field.getDOMNode().value };
},
```

Comment: Different from your issue, but there may also be an issue where onChange doesn't get called for autofilled values: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159.

Answer (score 2):

Using onChange event is the most common scenario to update whatever model property bound to a component, but you can also use onBlur to catch the values when the form is "auto-filled" by the browser.

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {typed: ''};
  },
  onBlur: function(event) {
    this.setState({typed: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
        <input type="text" onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}/>
        You typed: <code>{this.state.typed}</code>
      </div>
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using refs :) ..basically I trigger the change events manually for the first second..the reason behind is that every browser is handling autofill in a different way and this changes based on browser version..there is no way to cover this properly as of now

```
  componentDidMount () {
    let tries = 4;
    this.int  = setInterval(() => {
      tries--;
      if (tries === 0) {
        this._createChangeEvent();
        clearInterval(this.int);
      }
    }, 300);
  }

  _createChangeEvent = () => {
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
      const evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
      this.input.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {
      this.input.fireEvent("onchange");
    }
  };
```